# How does Nuget.VisualStudio IVsPackageInstallerEvents get invoked

Tags: nuget

I was looking for a way to hook into the Nuget Visual Studio UI/Console to be triggered on events and found there is a Nuget.VisualStudio.dll that has the events I want.

How would I register these events in my visual studio solution to be invoked when using the Nuget Dialog/Command Line? I can't seem to find a full example of this anywhere.

Links:

http://blog.nuget.org/20120926/invoking-nuget-services-from-inside-visual-studio.html

https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/visual-studio-extensibility/nuget-api-in-visual-studio

Thanks

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution/answer to this?

Comment: @bgeveritt nope. For the moment I am just manually doing the event myself before i perform the nuget action.